# Rails + Graphql: How to optimize the sql query before graphqls schema is being executed on the result?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, graphql, graphql-ruby

**Field**

```
module Types
  class QueryType < GraphQL::Schema::Object
      field :restaurants, [RestaurantType], null: true do
        description "Lists all restaurants"
      end

      def restaurants
        Restaurant.all
      end
    end
  end
```

**Query**

```
query Restaurants {
  restaurants {
    name
    cuisine
  }
}
```

In the example above, `Restaurants.all` will initially get all the rows from the `restaurant` table and then filter them out according to the query.

This is quite inefficient as we can use the query to filter out our data on the actual sql request:

```
module Types
  class QueryType < GraphQL::Schema::Object
    field :restaurant, RestaurantType, null: true do
      description "Find a restaurant by ID"
      argument :id, Int, required: true
    end

    field :restaurants, [RestaurantType], null: true, resolve: -> (obj, args, ctx) {
                                        children = ctx.irep_node.scoped_children
                                        root_key = children.keys.first
                                        params = children[root_key].keys
                                        Restaurant.all.select(params.join(", "))
                                      } do
      description "Lists all restaurants"
    end
  end
end
```

The underline sql representation is then

**Option A**
`SELECT "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants"` - returns more rows than needed

**Option B**
`SELECT name, cuisine FROM "restaurants"` - only returns the requested rows

This is **not** ideal as it won't work with joins, unless explicitly handled.

Since I'm quite new to Ruby and/or Rails I've been wondering if that's a good practice, or are there any other ways to achieve such optimization?

Comment: Both `SELECT` statements you mention will select the same number of rows. The difference will be in the columns, all (*) vs. only name/cuisine